# Receive inaudible sound at ~20khz

Tags: arduino, atmel, sound

I'm looking into receiving data to toggle a led. The data would have to come from a microphone that picks up sound at inaudible frequencies transmitted by standard speakers (TV, PC).

I've looked at ultrasonic sensors but they work at 40khz instead, which cannot be relied on because the speakers might not support it.

Microphones ranging from 20hz to 20khz can be had cheaply. [Looking at this page](http://blog.theultimatelabs.com/2013/05/wirelessly-communicating-with-arduino.html), it seems to put quite a burden to check the frequencies with Arduino timers. I figure there must be a simpler way to do it instead. Is there? Can I do it without an Atmel processor? I'm not very familiar with sound workings in electronics, so excuse my ignorance.

Comment: (1) Regular speakers won't be very efficient at 20 kHz. (2) If you're planning on using the TV or PC to produce the signal it probably won't work as they will low-pass filter the signal and attenuate or eliminate it. (3) To detect the signal you would use an analog amplifier with a band-pass filter set to 20 kHz. This will only give an output if your transmitter signal is picked up, a dog whistle is blown or a bat passes by. (4) The output would need a threshold detector to give you a digital signal.

Comment: Check [**this**](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/knowles/SPH0641LU4H-1/423-1402-1-ND/5332430) out.

Comment: Do you want to merely check for the presence of ultrasound or do you want to actually measure its frequency?  The former is easy, the latter more difficult.

Comment: @transistor From what I gather advertisements and such use the same frequency from 19 to 22khz to track phones.

Comment: @EMFields Practically I only need to detect it for a lightswitch toggle. There may be a couple of false positives, but preferably not.

Comment: Once the ultrasound is detected and the LED lights up, do you want the LED to:  **1.** stay lit until you reset it manually, re-arming the detector for the next hit, **2.** stay lit until another ultrasound signal toggles it OFF and re-arms the detector for the next hit, **3.** stay lit for a fixed time until a timer turns it OFF and re-arms the detector for the next hit,  or **4.** something else?. Also,  assuming the detector can detect signals in a band between a low frequency and a high frequency, what would you want those limit frequencies to be?

Comment: `Can I do it without an Atmel processor?` Yes, it can be done with no processor at all.

Comment: @EMFields (3) It stays on for a small fixed time (30-100ms) and then shuts off again until it receives a new signal. I can work around occasional false positives (say one per three seconds). The signals are submitted min. 1 per three seconds to max. 1 per 0.5 seconds, with the first being more likely.

Comment: This is starting to annoy the system, so I'll submit a preliminary answer just to get the ball rolling, and I'm assuming that these ultrasonic signals are transient in nature and are, essentially, tone bursts. What's the lowest and highest frequency you want to detect and what's the length, in time, of the shortest tone burst you want to detect?

Comment: Unless you have a quiet environment or a very strong source you will probably need more sophisticated modulation than on-off keying, and a corresponding detector.

Comment: As a note: 20kHz will not be universally inaudible and, depending on the signal generation technique, may drift downwards in frequency. *Someone* could hear your device and figure to turn off your device. Starting at 25kHz or higher would be a good idea to avoid this issue.

Comment: @user2943160 The sound will be very short single bursts and occassional. I think 25khz is not produced by most standard speakers, or it may be filtered out.

Comment: @RobotRock as has been mentioned, the speakers/microphones *can* generate sound above 20kHz, but they are not specified/rated/characterized above this frequency. Yes, there will be a filtering effect, but with low cost speakers/microphones, you will see filtering even by 20kHz.

Comment: @user2943160 Ah I see, thanks for that info. That would require me to use higher soundsampling though, correct? Instead of regular 44khz I would need more than 2x25khz. I will look into it.

Comment: @RobotRock operating at nearly the Nyquist frequency (in direct-sampling applications, half of your sample rate) may cause your signal processing to be difficult, if done digitally. It can be acceptable, with appropriate DAC filtering, for the output, but digital receive can be complicated near the Nyquist frequency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of those very inexpensive "jelly bean" commodity electret microphone capsules have frequency response above 20 KHz. So finding a sensor for 20 KHz should not be a significant issue.  They typically don't publish specifications for frequency response above 20 KHZ because most applications don't require it.

If you used an amplifier stage and a resonant circuit detector (or PLL, etc.), then you could feed the "demodulated" signal directly into your microcontroller (Arduino, etc.) input pin. Making the MC detect 20 KHz would not be anybody's first choice of solutions.  A commonly used chip for tone detection is LM567.

Comment: Actually most electrets are pretty bad at ~20 KHz, though the physicaly smallest may do slightly better.

Comment: Thanks, Richard. A tone decoder seems to be what I need.

Answer (score 2):

While ultrasonic electrets exist, common MEMS microphones potentially work a lot better than common electrets at these near-ultrasonic frequencies.  However those with onboard digital conversion may block it, so an analog one is preferred.

Common audio sources and speakers can typically produce a useful signal even though they are not designed to, but analog broadcast formats and the lower bitrate digital ones may not be able to carry one.

You will probably want an MCU wth an audio class ADC if you intend to pursue a digital decoding that works in the presence of background noise.

You will probably also want a modulation and demodulation scheme more sophisticated than on-off keying.

Comment: Thanks for the headsup on audio sources. I will be using digital sound, so I will keep an eye on bitrate. I figure going without an MCU won't get me there, so I will include it in my design.

Answer (score 1):

This is padding. This is a start:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @EMFields. Frequency should be between (abs min.) 15 and (max) 20 khz (likely around 19, say 18 to 20 as I figure outputted frequencies might differ slightly for different devices). Tone burst length should be max. 0.5 sec, but I'd rather have it as short as possible because it affects latency (which is important in my case). 15ms is ideal for me.

Comment: For now I'm thinking maybe going with an Atmel MCU anyway, because I fear that the complexity grows, rather than lowers, and I'm starting off with a prototype. I found [this microphone](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1063) supports frequencies up to 20Khz. On the long term, the Atmel MCU has to go. Looking at your diagram and others' comments I then need: a tone decoder (NE567/LM567), a microphone, a timer, MOSFET/transistor for the leds (2 low powered), a lowpass filter to remove background noise.